# How to use <uses-library> at AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android

If I have an android app and want to use a filter so the android app can only be installed to devices that has specific library e.g. /system/lib/libabc.so
This library is not available to all devices, it depends on the chips company.

According to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-library-element.html, I can use

I tried by adding below line at my AndroidManifest.mk and have libabc.so at /system/lib/

```
<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:debuggable="true">

<uses-library 
android:name="libabc.so"
android:required="true"/>
...

</application>
```

However, I still get error like below
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
Please check logcat output for more details.
Launch canceled!

Question: How should i put the name at "android:name" to correlate to the required library at /system/lib/libabc.so ?

Comment: I don't think `<uses-library>` maps to native libraries. I think it maps to Java libraries that happen to be part of the firmware and are published as an SDK add-on. There have been some presentations on SDK add-ons in the past year by Dario Laverde, such as http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/agile-scrum/extending-the-android-sdk-add-ons

Comment: Then is there any method for filtering the native library so that we can't install the apk if the native library is not available?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.